# Checking whether all enum values are mapped?

Tags: java, enums

Is there a convenience method available in the java standard libraries to check whether all possible keys in an EnumMap are mapped to a value?

I can write my own method like:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> boolean areAllValuesMapped(EnumMap<T, ?> map, Class<T> enumClass)
{
    return map.keySet().equals(EnumSet.allOf(enumClass));
}
```

But then I'm repeating the Class parameter (already given in the EnumMap constructor) as well as creating throwaway KeySet and EnumSet objects. EnumMap should have enough information to do this efficiently as an internal operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this that I can find in `EnumMap` (and I checked the source code to be sure). However, here is a slightly quicker method:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> boolean areAllValuesMapped(EnumMap<T,?> map, Class<T> enumClass) {
    return map.size() == enumClass.getEnumConstants().length;
}
```

I should note that `EnumMap.keySet()` does not return an `EnumSet`; if it did, the `equals()` call that you use would be a simple matter of comparing `longs`. As it is, it has to use an iterator and check each enum constant sequentially.

Comment: Note that Class#getEnumConstants() clones the underlying array; that may be a cost worth avoiding if caching the size is possible. Also, note that Class#getEnumConstants() will return null if the class doesn't actually extend `Enum`. Here you've qualified the type parameter `T` properly to guard against that, so I guess that if the caller does some malfeasant casting to pass in an illegal class, encountering a thrown `NullPointerException` will an acceptable punishment. Throwing `IllegalArgumentException` would be appropriate too. Usually I write `assert null != constants;`.